# Contents within an attribute for both single and multiple ending tags

Tags: regex

How can I fetch the contents within value attribute of the below tag across the files

```
<h:graphicImage .... value="*1.png*" ...../>
<h:graphicImage .... value="*2.png*" ....>...</h:graphicImage>
```

My regular expression search result should result into

- 1.png
- 2.png

All I could find was content for multiple ending tags but what about the single ending tags.

Comment: You shouldn't use regex to try to parse xml/html. This is the classic answer to why: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags#answer-1732454. Use a parser instead, you'll avoid banging your head on weird bugs for hours.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use an XML parser instead, regex cannot truly parse XML properly, unless you know the input will always follow a particular form.

However, here is a regex you can use to extract the value attribute of `h:graphicImage` tags, but read the caveats after:

```
<h:graphicImage[^>]+value="\*(.*?)\*"
```

and the `1.png` or `2.png` will be in the first captured group.

Caveats:

- here I have assumed that your `1.png`, `2.png` etc are always surrounded by asterisks as that is what it seems from your question (that is what the `\*` is for)
- this regex will fail if one of the attributes has a ">" character in it, for example

  ```
  <h:graphicImage foo=">" value="*1.png*"
  ```

  This is what I mentioned before about regex never being able to parse XML properly.
  You could work around this by adjusting your regex:

  ```
  <h:graphicImage.+?+value="\*(.*?)\*"
  ```

  But this means that if you had `<h:graphicImage /><foo value="*1.png*">` then the `1.png` from the `foo` tag is extracted, when you only want to extract from the `graphicImage` tag.
  Again, regex will always have issues with corner cases for XML, so you need to adjust according to your application (for example, if you know that *only* the graphicImage tag will *ever* have a "value" attribute, then the second case may be better than the first).